# Invalid identifier error when trying to create table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, create-table

Hi I am using Oracle SQL to make a table, however I am getting this error and I'm not sure why.

Error:

```
Error report -
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

sql:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id                 number(8)
                            NOT NULL
                            CONSTRAINT user_id_pk
                            PRIMARY KEY,

    first_name              varchar(64)

    gender                  number(1)
                            NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: You have a comma before `)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple errors.  You want:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id number(8) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT user_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name varchar2(64),
    gender  number(1) NOT NULL
);
```

Note that the name is `varchar2()`.  This is the recommended string type in Oracle.